# How to use Julia to do Named Semaphore under linux?

Tags: ipc, julia, semaphore

To do Inter-Process communication between Julia process and other running processes written in C, C++ or Julia, I'd like to use named-semaphore for synchronization purpose. However it seems not working for

1. named semaphore won't be shared between processes
2. incorrect initial value

I'm in julia-0.5.2 and following codes:

```
function sem_open(sem_seg_name::String; is_creator::Bool=false)::Ref{Cint}
    permission = Base.S_IRUSR | Base.S_IWUSR | Base.S_IRGRP | Base.S_IROTH # 0644

    sem_t = is_creator ?
        ccall(:sem_open, Cint, (Cstring, Cint, Base.Cmode_t, Cuint), sem_seg_name, Base.JL_O_CREAT, permission, Cuint(1)) :
        ccall(:sem_open, Cint, (Cstring, Cint),                      sem_seg_name, Base.JL_O_RDWR)
    systemerror(string("sem_open failed to ", (is_creator?"create":"open"), " semaphore for ", sem_seg_name), sem_t == 0)
    return sem_t
end
```

will create a file /dev/shm/sem.xxx.

But semaphore value is totally random everything time the process started, as if ignoring the last argument of the C Api:

```
sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode, unsigned int value);
```

Also another process opening this named semaphore will get a different value. I can use ccall(:sem_init) to set value and post/wait on it as usual, but it only work in the same process.

Can Julia ccall works on named semaphore?

Comment: "works for me" on ubuntu 14.04 and Julia 0.5.2 and 0.6. I changed the return type to Ptr{Void} (needs to be Ptr{_something_}; see the sem_open documentation, it will vary by platform). Note that Cint (int32) will be truncated on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Thank you, it seems fix my problem.